# How to use $in or $nin in mongo aggregation $group $cond

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to achieve $sum with $cond by having $or on property:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate(
{
   "$group": {
     "_id":'$created_at',
     "count": {"$sum": 1},
     "count_failure": {
         "$sum": {
           "$cond": [
               {
                 "$id":
                  { "$in": [ 0,100,101,102,103,104,105 ] }
               }, 
               1,
               0
              ] 
           }
         }
    }  
 }
)
```

But error says: `Invalid operator "$id"`

What's wrong with syntax? Or I am writing query wrongly.

Currently I am achieving this by:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate(
{
   "$group": {
     "_id":'$created_at',
     "count": {"$sum": 1},
     "count_failure": {
         "$sum": {
           "$cond": [
               {
                 "$or":[
                  { "$eq": [ "$id", 0 ] },
                  { "$eq": [ "$id", 100 ]},
                  { "$eq": [ "$id", 101 ]},
                  { "$eq": [ "$id", 102 ]},
                  { "$eq": [ "$id", 103 ]},
                  { "$eq": [ "$id", 104 ]},
                  { "$eq": [ "$id", 105 ]}
                 ]
               }, 
               1,
               0
              ] 
           }
         }
   }  
 }
)
```

Comment: It looks like [since version 3.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) that `$in` is now supported in a `cond` predicate in the aggregation pipeline

Comment: $in: ["$$id",[0,100,101,102,......]] that's it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The comparison on [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) is a shorter option than the `$or` condition you are using, though it's still basically valid to do what you are doing.

The only catch with `$setIsSubset` is that each argument is an array so you need to convert the single element as a single element array. This is easy enough using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/):

```js
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$createdAt",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 },
        "count_failure": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$setIsSubset": [
                        { "$map": {
                            "input": ["A"],
                            "as": "el",
                            "in": "$id"
                        }},
                        [ 0,100,101,102,103,104,105 ],
                    ]},
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }}    
])
```

Or if you prefer, then match the array of arguments against the singular value instead, with [`$anyElementTrue`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/):

```js
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$createdAt",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 },
        "count_failure": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$anyElementTrue": { "$map": {
                        "input": [ 0,100,101,102,103,104,105 ],
                        "as": "el",
                        "in": { "$eq": [ "$$el", "$id" ] }
                    }}},
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Where the `$map` is rather traversing the arguments to match to the singular rather than forcing the singular into an array.

And of course since either form is essentially supplying `true/false` to the `$cond` then you can just reverse the logic with [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/not/) where required:

```js
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$createdAt",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 },
        "count_failure": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$not": [{ "$anyElementTrue": { "$map": {
                        "input": [ 0,100,101,102,103,104,105 ],
                        "as": "el",
                        "in": { "$eq": [ "$$el", "$id" ] }
                    }}}]},
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

It really depends on how you look at it, but simply as supplied arguments then you don't really gain anything over the original form with `$or`. It might look a little cleaner and "easier to type", but typically I would not be "typing" such logic into the aggregation pipeline directly, but rather generating that part of the structure based on a plain list in the first place:

i.e

```js
var failList = [ 0,100,101,102,103,104,105 ];

var orCondition = failList.map(function(el) { 
    return { "$eq": [ "$id", el ] }
})
```

And then just using the re-mapped array content in the pipeline definition:

```js
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$createdAt",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 },
        "count_failure": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$or": orCondition },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Whatever way you look at it, remember it's all just data structures and you have basic processes for manipulating. Both inside the pipeline processing and also in the pipeline construction itself.

Comment: 1st way somewhat hard. 2nd one is easy. Though there should be easy $or in $group? Hope mongo releases this feature.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk I think you mean "3rd way" given the three approaches shown, and for the record just about all of my code doing something like this does it that way, as it's the logical approach. If you mean that you want an `$in` clause, then consider that you are asking this to feed to `$cond` in the first place, so what exactly is the syntax for such an operation? Where do you specify the field you want to compare to? You are welcome to post a [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) with any such suggestion.

Comment: Yes I mean 2nd and 3rd ones are easy. And there is already suggestion given as https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6146

Comment: @SomnathMuluk I did note the issue after posting the comment, and if you feel it is worthwhile then please vote. However the issue is a few years old and actually pre-dates operators like `$map` or `$setIsSubset`, and thus these operators can be viewed as the current implemented solution. The issue also lacks input on what a "proposed" syntax could be. Which is generally the largest issue. If you want it, "then ask", and hence make a proposal to a desired syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think that $in isn't an aggregation pipeline operator.

Comment: How to use "$setIsSubset" instead of "$In"?

Comment: Syntax: `{ $setIsSubset: [ <expression1>, <expression2> ] }`. 
You need to put your element "id" in a matrix. But on second thought, I think that it isn't the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

First you should create a list of `$id` using [$map](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) in project and then use [setIsSubset](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) in group as below :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([{
  "$project": {
    "idsArray": {
      "$map": {
        "input": ["A"],
        "as": "el",
        "in": {
          "$cond": [{
              "$eq": ["$$el", "A"]
            }, "$id",
            null
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$created_at",
    "count": {
      "$sum": 1
    },
    "count_failure": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{
            "$setIsSubset": ["$idsArray", [
              0,
              100,
              101,
              102,
              103,
              104,
              105
            ]]
          },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}])
```