# Can you do a MongoDB aggregate projection operator $in

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Can you do a MongoDB aggregate projection operator `{$cond: { '$field': {$in: ['val1', 'val2']}}}`? Or I have to break it into `$or`?

Currently I have a:

```
$project: {
  countNames: [
     // if
     {$or: [
       {$eq: ['$name', 'Frist variant']},
       {$eq: ['$name', 'Second variant']}
     ]
     // then
     1,
     // else
     0
   ]
 }
```

I just wonder if there is a way to avoid those repeating *`$eq`'s*, something like:

```
sum: {
  $cond: [
     '$name': {$in: ['Frist', 'Second']},
     1,
     0
  ]
}
```

Okay, I know that the version I wrote doesn't work (tried it), but is there an operator that can do it? Repeating $eq's gets old quickly when there are more of them, I sometimes resort to multi-stage pipe, or mapReduce instead. This would help up with some of my code.

For what it's worth, I'm currently on MongoDB 2.6, but I plan to switch production to Mongo 3 within weeks, so v3 solution will also be acceptable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use $in or $nin in mongo aggregation $group $cond](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734923/how-to-use-in-or-nin-in-mongo-aggregation-group-cond)

Comment: Seems like I could use it, I'll try and update or delete my question.